# AWS Glue pysaprk error: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

My cluster config: `Worker type G2X(8 VCPU, 32GB RAM), Number of worker 8`

Below is my code: Basically I am reading from aws glue catalog database table, creating dataframe, flattening columns and then writes data into postgress table.I need to get the count, so I am persisting dataframe and then using `unpersist('True')`

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, functions as F
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.gluetypes import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark
from ssm_cache import SSMParameter
import gs_flatten
import pandas as pd
import botocore.exceptions
import random

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'transaction_id', 'cohort_no', 'glue_db'])

transaction_id = args['transaction_id']
cohort_no = args['cohort_no']
glue_db = args["glue_db"]

def insert_db_claim_service(df, table_name, mode):
    # before this my rdd num partion is 30 and since I am using 8 workes(including 1 driver) with 8 vcpu, repartitioning to 56(7*8)
    df.repartition(56).write.format("jdbc") \ 
        .option("url", jdbc_url) \
        .option("dbtable", f"{pg_patient_schemaname}.{table_name}") \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .option("stringtype", "unspecified") \
        .option("batchsize", "250000") \
        .mode(mode) \
        .save()

def flatten_dataframe(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    schema = df.schema()
    cols_to_explode = []
    try:
        for col in schema.fields:
            if isinstance(col.dataType, ArrayType):
                cols_to_explode.append(col.name)
        if len(cols_to_explode) > 0:
            for col in cols_to_explode:
                df = df.withColumn(col, F.explode(col))
            df = df.gs_flatten()
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        raise e



def get_s3_path(table_name):
    client = boto3.client('glue')
    response = client.get_table(
        DatabaseName=glue_db,
        Name=table_name
    )
    service_location = response['Table']['StorageDescriptor']['Location']
    service_location = service_location.split('/')
    service_location = '/'.join(service_location[3:])
    s3_file_info = {}
    for file in get_s3_objects(boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-2'), Bucket=bkt_nm,
                               Prefix=service_location):
        if file['Key'].endswith('.parquet'):
            s3_file_info[f"s3://{bkt_nm}/{file['Key']}"] = int(file['Size']) / (1024 * 1024)

    df = pd.DataFrame(s3_file_info.items(), columns=['s3_path', 'size'])
    df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42).reset_index(drop=True)

    num_files_per_group = int(batch_size) # batch_size value is set to 30
    num_groups = len(df) // num_files_per_group
    start_idx = 0
    s3_path = []
    size_result = []
    for _ in range(num_groups):
        group = df.iloc[start_idx:start_idx + num_files_per_group].copy()
        group_paths = group['s3_path'].tolist()
        s3_path.append(group_paths)
        size_result.append(group['size'].sum())
        start_idx += num_files_per_group

    remaining_files = len(df) % num_files_per_group
    if remaining_files > 0:
        remaining_group = df.iloc[start_idx:].copy()
        remaining_paths = remaining_group['s3_path'].tolist()
        s3_path.append(remaining_paths)
        size_result.append(remaining_group['size'].sum())
    print(size_result)
    return s3_path

def main():
    s3_paths = get_s3_path(table_name)
    print(f"total no of batch for {table_name}:{str(len(s3_paths))}")
    batch = 0
    claim_service_rec_cnt = 0
    table_name = f"dtsrc_{table_name}_{cohort_no}"
    for s3_path in s3_paths:
        df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            connection_type="s3",
            format="parquet",
            connection_options={"paths": s3_path},
            transformation_ctx='df'
        )
        df = flatten_dataframe(df)
        df = df.toDF()
        df = df.na.drop(subset=["`LINE_DIAGNOSYS.DIAGNOSIS_VAL`",
                                "`DIAGNOSYS.DIAGNOSIS_VAL`"])
        df.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        insert_db_claim_service(df, table_name, 'append')

        claim_service_rec_cnt = claim_service_rec_cnt + df.count()
        df.unpersist(blocking=True)
        print(f"Processing completed for {str(batch)}")
        batch = batch + 1
    rec_count_dict[table_name] = str(claim_service_rec_cnt)
    print(f"Processing completed for {table_name}")

    df_ = pd.DataFrame(list(rec_count_dict.items()), columns=['table_name', 'rec_count'])
    df_.to_csv(f"s3://{bkt_nm}/{temp_dir}rec_count.csv", index=False)

    job.commit()
```

In my source there are total 3031 files(total 42 gb) and I am processing 30 files each time.Average input size for 30 files is around 450-460 mb. Even if the input size is less and i am using high configuration still I am getting this error.I have really no clue why this is happending!

For few batches it's running fine. For example for batch 1, my input size is 469.7 MiB and shiffle read is 19.2 gb and shuffle write is 19.2 gb it ran fine.
for batch 11 my input size of 30 files is 458 MIB and I see 57 task failed due to above issue.

I am using `df.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` follwed by `df.count()` to get the count of records for each batch. By any chnace is it creating issue?

By default I can see from spark UI the executor memeory is allocated 11.8GB.Also I have noticed that for successful batch the shiffle read/write is huge, approxmimately average close to 20gb

error:

```
23/06/02 19:20:19 ERROR GlueExceptionAnalysisListener: [Glue Exception Analysis] {
    "Event": "GlueExceptionAnalysisStageFailed",
    "Timestamp": 1685733619070,
    "Failure Reason": "org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: The relative remote executor(Id: 1), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead.",
    "Stack Trace": [
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "throwFetchFailedException",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 770
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "next",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 685
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "next",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 70
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator",
            "Method Name": "next",
            "File Name": "CompletionIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 29
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10",
            "Method Name": "next",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 455
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11",
            "Method Name": "nextCur",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 480
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 486
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 454
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "CompletionIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 31
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "InterruptibleIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 37
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 454
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 454
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10",
            "Method Name": "hasNext",
            "File Name": "Iterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 454
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$",
            "Method Name": "savePartition",
            "File Name": "JdbcUtils.scala",
            "Line Number": 672
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$saveTable$1",
            "File Name": "JdbcUtils.scala",
            "Line Number": 856
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted",
            "File Name": "JdbcUtils.scala",
            "Line Number": 854
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$foreachPartition$2",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 1020
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 1020
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.SparkContext",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$runJob$5",
            "File Name": "SparkContext.scala",
            "Line Number": 2278
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask",
            "Method Name": "runTask",
            "File Name": "ResultTask.scala",
            "Line Number": 90
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task",
            "Method Name": "run",
            "File Name": "Task.scala",
            "Line Number": 131
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner",
            "Method Name": "$anonfun$run$3",
            "File Name": "Executor.scala",
            "Line Number": 497
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.util.Utils$",
            "Method Name": "tryWithSafeFinally",
            "File Name": "Utils.scala",
            "Line Number": 1439
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner",
            "Method Name": "run",
            "File Name": "Executor.scala",
            "Line Number": 500
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor",
            "Method Name": "runWorker",
            "File Name": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "Line Number": 1149
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker",
            "Method Name": "run",
            "File Name": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "Line Number": 624
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "java.lang.Thread",
            "Method Name": "run",
            "File Name": "Thread.java",
            "Line Number": 750
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": " org.apache.spark.ExecutorDeadException: The relative remote executor(Id: 1), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead.",
            "Method Name": "CausedBy",
            "File Name": "CausedBy",
            "Line Number": -1
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2",
            "Method Name": "createAndStart",
            "File Name": "NettyBlockTransferService.scala",
            "Line Number": 133
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher",
            "Method Name": "fetchAllOutstanding",
            "File Name": "RetryingBlockFetcher.java",
            "Line Number": 153
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher",
            "Method Name": "start",
            "File Name": "RetryingBlockFetcher.java",
            "Line Number": 133
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService",
            "Method Name": "fetchBlocks",
            "File Name": "NettyBlockTransferService.scala",
            "Line Number": 143
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "sendRequest",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 283
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "send$1",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 743
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "fetchUpToMaxBytes",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 738
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "initialize",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 552
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator",
            "Method Name": "<init>",
            "File Name": "ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala",
            "Line Number": 171
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.shuffle.io.LocalDiskShuffleReadSupport",
            "Method Name": "getPartitionReaders",
            "File Name": "LocalDiskShuffleReadSupport.scala",
            "Line Number": 77
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.io.LocalDiskShuffleExecutorComponents",
            "Method Name": "getPartitionReaders",
            "File Name": "LocalDiskShuffleExecutorComponents.java",
            "Line Number": 99
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader",
            "Method Name": "read",
            "File Name": "BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala",
            "Line Number": 107
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD",
            "Method Name": "compute",
            "File Name": "ShuffledRowRDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 212
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "computeOrReadCheckpoint",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 373
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "iterator",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 337
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD",
            "Method Name": "compute",
            "File Name": "MapPartitionsRDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 52
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "computeOrReadCheckpoint",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 373
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "iterator",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 337
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD",
            "Method Name": "compute",
            "File Name": "SQLExecutionRDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 55
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "computeOrReadCheckpoint",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 373
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "iterator",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 337
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD",
            "Method Name": "compute",
            "File Name": "MapPartitionsRDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 52
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "computeOrReadCheckpoint",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 373
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD",
            "Method Name": "iterator",
            "File Name": "RDD.scala",
            "Line Number": 337
        }
    ],
    "Stage ID": 68,
    "Stage Attempt ID": 0,
    "Number of Tasks": 56
}
```